# Azure Functions Proxy 404 on localhost

Tags: azure, proxy, localhost, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App with a function at the URL `http://localhost:7072/api/create-room` along with other functions. This particular function is a `HTTPTrigger` with allowed anonymous access and accepts the `GET` verb:

```cs
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")]
```

Along with that, I have a separate function app that hosts only a `proxies.json` file and serves only as a functions proxy. My proxies function is running on port `7071` locally.

My proxies file currently looks like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
      "chatNegotiate": {
        "matchCondition": {
          "route": "/api/chat/negotiate",
          "methods": [
            "POST"
          ]
        },
        "backendUri": "%chat_api%/api/BeginNegotiate"
      },
      "chatMessages": {
        "matchCondition": {
          "route": "/api/chat/messages",
          "methods": [
            "POST"
          ]
        },
        "backendUri": "%chat_api%/api/PostMessage"
      },
      "createRoom": {
        "matchCondition": {
          "route": "/api/create-room",
          "methods": [
            "GET"
          ]
        },
        "backendUri": "%session_api%/api/CreateRoom"
      }
    }
}
```

When both of these function apps are deployed to Azure, everything works like a dream. I can make requests, they're forwarded on, requests come back. It's all glorious.

However, when I run these functions locally, the request is never forwarded on from the proxy, with the proxy returning a 404. I can hit the function on the other function app running locally on `7072` directly and all is well there, but not at all when I got via the proxy.

The proxy itself returns:

```
[30/05/2020 18:24:30] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000002D5B6BEA'.
[30/05/2020 18:24:34] Executing HTTP request: {
[30/05/2020 18:24:34]   "requestId": "9004b8e2-f208-4a98-8b48-6f85bca41281",
[30/05/2020 18:24:34]   "method": "GET",
[30/05/2020 18:24:34]   "uri": "/api/create-room"
[30/05/2020 18:24:34] }
[30/05/2020 18:24:34] Executed HTTP request: {
[30/05/2020 18:24:34]   "requestId": "9004b8e2-f208-4a98-8b48-6f85bca41281",
[30/05/2020 18:24:34]   "method": "GET",
[30/05/2020 18:24:34]   "uri": "/api/create-room",
[30/05/2020 18:24:34]   "identities": [],
[30/05/2020 18:24:34]   "status": 404,
[30/05/2020 18:24:34]   "duration": 15
[30/05/2020 18:24:34] }
```

From examples I've looked at such as https://chsakell.com/2019/02/03/azure-functions-proxies-in-action/, this should be working fine.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Have you updated your local.settings.json in the local?

Comment: If you are getting a 404 then it means you are calling a wrong URL. Make sure you have all the variables you have in production on your local.settings.json. You can also try to hardcode localhost:7072 on your proxies to debug

Comment: My local.settings.json is up to date and correct for the proxy. I’ve also tried it hard coded with the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved this after all.

proxies.json isn't set to copy to the output directory by default.

You need to ensure that it's set to **copy always**.

**In Visual Studio:**

Right click `proxies.json` > click **properties** > Set **Copy to output directory** to **Copy Always**.

**In Visual Studio Code (and other editors):**
Open `ProjectName.csproj` and add an entry to always copy `proxies.json` to output directory.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="proxies.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem, it's incredibly annoying. Don't get this solution though, is this something in the editor? I use VSCode and don't get that option.

Comment: Having exactly the same issue, but sadly your solution isn't working for me.

Comment: @Jānis the solution also didn’t work for me, did you ever find a solution? The same proxy file works in azure portal but locally for me

Comment: @gman9732 I did. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68632947/3633935
There are similar answers already here, but in mine there is also answer to additional blocker you might find.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem with the 404 on my local instance of the function app proxy.  In local.settings.json add this to Values:

"AZURE_FUNCTION_PROXY_DISABLE_LOCAL_CALL": true,

Credit: https://chsakell.com/2019/02/03/azure-functions-proxies-in-action/

Comment: Not working for me.