# Azure Functions proxy returns 404 on localhost only

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-functions

I have what seems to be an identical issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107056/azure-functions-proxy-404-on-localhost), but the solution is not working - proxies.json was and is set to "copy always".

I have .net core API with Azure Functions v2 and docker container to which I want to proxy some requests. Everything works fine when deployed, but locally proxy returns 404 response.

`proxies.json`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "review": {
      "debug": true,
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "api/{docId}/proxy/review/{*restOfPath}"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://my-docker-container.azurewebsites.net/{restOfPath}",
      "requestOverrides": {
        "backend.request.headers.Some-Header": "request.headers.Cookie"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Local docker container is listening on port 3000, so I replace `backendUri` with `http://localhost:3000/{restOfPath}`, but it returns 404. Docker endpoint is never hit. I can confirm that docker container is running and working by calling expected URL from Postman.

Besides to solution, is there some way I can try to debug this somehow more? Can't get anything useful from logs.

Successful log when using deployed resource:

```
[2021-08-02 10:01:06] Executing HTTP request: {
[2021-08-02 10:01:06]   "requestId": "8c60239b-046d-464b-8a3a-09e0f5c55090",
[2021-08-02 10:01:06]   "method": "POST",
[2021-08-02 10:01:06]   "uri": "/api/4708a861-d8b2-4033-a1da-1a07afca4161/proxy/review/api/review"
[2021-08-02 10:01:06] }
[2021-08-02 10:01:06] Function started (Id=ebfbabc0-1a5b-4129-9280-14ae322e23ba)
[2021-08-02 10:01:06] Executing 'Functions.review' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=ebfbabc0-1a5b-4129-9280-14ae322e23ba)
[2021-08-02 10:01:06] Executing request via Azure Function Proxies
[2021-08-02 10:01:22] Function completed (Success, Id=ebfbabc0-1a5b-4129-9280-14ae322e23ba, Duration=16363ms)
[2021-08-02 10:01:22] Executed 'Functions.review' (Succeeded, Id=ebfbabc0-1a5b-4129-9280-14ae322e23ba)
[2021-08-02 10:01:22] Executed HTTP request: {
[2021-08-02 10:01:22]   "requestId": "8c60239b-046d-464b-8a3a-09e0f5c55090",
[2021-08-02 10:01:22]   "method": "POST",
[2021-08-02 10:01:22]   "uri": "/api/4708a861-d8b2-4033-a1da-1a07afca4161/proxy/review/api/review",
[2021-08-02 10:01:22]   "authorizationLevel": "Anonymous",
[2021-08-02 10:01:22]   "status": "OK"
[2021-08-02 10:01:22] }
```

Unsuccessful log using local resource:

```
[2021-08-02 07:58:02] Executing HTTP request: {
[2021-08-02 07:58:02]   "requestId": "f562eae9-b2c7-4ef8-84ba-83d42f59c4b7",
[2021-08-02 07:58:02]   "method": "POST",
[2021-08-02 07:58:02]   "uri": "/api/4708a861-d8b2-4033-a1da-1a07afca4161/proxy/review/api/review"
[2021-08-02 07:58:02] }
[2021-08-02 07:58:02] Function started (Id=28149473-125c-4fc4-958d-348604559e10)
[2021-08-02 07:58:02] Executing 'Functions.review' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=28149473-125c-4fc4-958d-348604559e10)
[2021-08-02 07:58:02] Executing request via Azure Function Proxies
[2021-08-02 07:58:02] Function completed (Success, Id=28149473-125c-4fc4-958d-348604559e10, Duration=169ms)
[2021-08-02 07:58:02] Executed 'Functions.review' (Succeeded, Id=28149473-125c-4fc4-958d-348604559e10)
[2021-08-02 07:58:02] Executed HTTP request: {
[2021-08-02 07:58:02]   "requestId": "f562eae9-b2c7-4ef8-84ba-83d42f59c4b7",
[2021-08-02 07:58:02]   "method": "POST",
[2021-08-02 07:58:02]   "uri": "/api/4708a861-d8b2-4033-a1da-1a07afca4161/proxy/review/api/review",
[2021-08-02 07:58:02]   "authorizationLevel": "Anonymous",
[2021-08-02 07:58:02]   "status": "NotFound"
[2021-08-02 07:58:02] }
```

**UPDATE:**
If there was any doubt that maybe Docker has something to do with it, it can be crossed out. Created new dummy API and it's the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.
Thanks to https://markheath.net/post/azure-functions-v2-proxies.

Needed to add `"AZURE_FUNCTION_PROXY_DISABLE_LOCAL_CALL": true` in `local.settings.json`

After this stumbled upon another issue - slashes in `backendUri` were being encoded, so instead of e.g. `http://localhost:3000/api/review` it was calling `http://localhost:3000/api%2Freview`. Again, only local issue.

To fix this need to add `"AZURE_FUNCTION_PROXY_BACKEND_URL_DECODE_SLASHES": true` to `local.settings.json`